# How to set a PHP ini config setting for a specific (virtual) URL path in the apache conf?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, directory

I want to set a specific `upload_max_filesize` setting for a specific URL on my webserver. The URL path is not a real path since it is a apache rewritten seo friendly path.

This does seems not to work:

```
<Directory /var/www/test_upload>
   php_value upload_max_filesize 750M
</Directory>
```

The rewrite Rule in the .htacces file in the document root (/var/www/) looks like:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: Unless you are offering the upload option multiple times for multiple locations you can set globally in php.ini and not worry about setting it for a directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use a <[`Location`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#location)> rule instead of <`Directory`>. You could set the ini param in your PHP file as well, though.

Comment: Sounds good, I will try it!